# Does Regex's [m] flag must come with [g] flag?

Tags: javascript, regex

I read on MDN that :

```
m flag  / multiline :
```

> Treat beginning and end characters (^ and $) as working over multiple
>   lines

So I made a test (http://regexr.com?374jj) :

I have this simple regex :

`^[\s\S]{3}`

If I dont check `global` and `multiline`  :

[image]

If I check only `global` :

[image]

If I check both `global` + `multiline` :

[image]

So it seems that `multiline` works only with the `global` flag.

Does my observation/conclusions are right ?  Does multi line should be always with global ?

Comment: No. Try the same test with the regex that does not match the first line, such as `^[^a][\s\S]{2}`.

Comment: @DCoder that should be an answer, not a comment :-)

Comment: @DCoder I don't see how it helps - you just added a filter. (still each line is being compared to that condition)

Comment: Without multiline, `^[^a][\s\S]{2}` will not match at all (with or without global) because the initial `^` means the start of the whole input (i.e. the start of just the first line).  _With_ multiline but not global it'll match `b12`, with both multiline and global it'll match `b12` and `c12`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`m` doesn't require or imply `g`, no. Consider:

```
"foo\nbar".match(/^bar/)   // `null`
```

vs.

```
"foo\nbar".match(/^bar/m)  // ["bar"]
```

With the `m` flag, `^bar` matches because the `^` matches at the beginning of the *line*. Without it, there is no match, because `^` doesn't match at the beginning of the input string. The `m` flag has the analogous effect on the end-of-(line|input) anchor `$` as well.

The `g` flag comes into play when you need to do the match more than once. Consider this difference, for instance:

```
"foo\nbar\nfoo\nbar".replace(/^bar/m, "BAZ")
```

...which gives us:

```
foo
BAZ
foo
bar
```

Note that the second match wasn't replaced. Compare with the result if we add the `g` flag:

```
"foo\nbar\nfoo\nbar".replace(/^bar/mg, "BAZ")
```

...which gives us:

```
foo
BAZ
foo
BAZ
```

Note that all matches were replaced.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Because it stops after the first match.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: The tool must be stopping as of the first match.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder My Mistake was : I thought that multiline is recalculating each line regardless global flag. I guess I have to allow global flag  - if I want to see all lines. (pretty obvious , but now i fully understand what was happening).

Answer (score 2):

Well, it depends what you are trying to achieve. Without the *global* flag, you will only get the first match. Without the *multiline* flag, only the first line will be considered.